# SAS : PROC SQL : How to read a character format (dd/mm/yyyy) as date format without creating new column?

Tags: sql, sas

I have a character column which has dates (dd/mm/yyyy) in character format.

While applying filter (where clause), I need that these characters are recognized as dates in the where statement, without actually making any change to the existing column or without creating a new column.

How can I make this happen. 
Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: In the future please make sure to show an attempt of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

In `proc sql`, you can come close with `like`:

```
select (case when datecol like '__/__/____'
             then . . . 
             else . . .
        end)
```

This is only an approximation.  `_` is a wildcard that matches *any* character, not just numbers.  On the other hand, this is standard SQL, so it will work in any database.

Comment: This way might work if I have to filter by 1 date at a time. But how will I apply range of dates in filter?

Comment: @AbhasJangre . . . Your question is how to recognize strings that are recognized as dates, not how to use the values for comparison.

Answer (score 2):

The SAS `INPUT` function with a `?` informat modifier will convert a string (source value) to a result and *not* show an error if the source value is not conformant to the informat.

`INPUT` can be used in a `WHERE` statement or clause.  The input can also be part of a `BETWEEN` statement.

```
* some of these free form values are not valid date representations;

data have;
  length freeform_date_string $10;
  do x = 0 to 1e4-1;
    freeform_date_string = 
      substr(put(x,z4.),1,2) || '/' ||
      substr(put(x,z4.),3,2) || '/' ||
      '2018'
    ;
    output;
  end;
run;

* where statement;

data want;
  set have;
  where input(freeform_date_string,? ddmmyy10.);
run;

* where clause;

proc sql;
  create table want2 as
  select * from have
  where 
    input(freeform_date_string,? ddmmyy10.) is not null
  ;

* where clause with input used with between operator operands;

proc sql;
  create table want3 as
  select * from have
  where 
    input(freeform_date_string,? ddmmyy10.) 
    between
      '15-JAN-2018'D
    and
      '15-MAR-2018'D
  ;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not great idea to store date as character value, it can lead to lot of data accuracy related issues and you may not even know that you have data issues for a long time. say someone enters wrong character date and you may not even know. it is always good to maintain date as date value rather than as character value

In your code Filter dates using like becomes little complex for dates. You can try below code which will work for you by using input statement in where clause

```
 data have;
 input id datecolumn $10.;
  datalines;
  1 20/10/2018
  1 25/10/2018
  2 30/10/2018
  2 01/11/2018
  ;

 proc sql;
 create table want as 
  select *  from have
 where input(datecolumn, ddmmyy10.) between '20Oct2018'd and '30Oct2018'd ;
```

using like as shown below for above same code

```
proc sql;
create table want as 
 select *  from have
 /*include all dates which start with 2 */
 where datecolumn like '2%' and  datecolumn like '%10/2018' 
 or datecolumn = '30/10/2018';
```

**Edit1:**

looks like you have data quality issue and sample dataset is shown below. try this. Once again i want to say approach of storing dates as character values is not good and can lead to lot of issues in future.

```
   data have;
  input id datecolumn $10.;
  datalines;
   1 20/10/2018
   1 25/10/2018
   2 30/10/2018
   2 01/11/2018
   3 01/99/2018
   ;

   proc sql;
  create table want(drop=newdate) as 
  select *,  case  when input(datecolumn, ddmmyy10.) ne .
                  then input(datecolumn, ddmmyy10.)
                    else . end as newdate from have
where calculated newdate between '20Oct2018'd and '30Oct2018'd
```

;

or you can put your case statement without making and dropping new column as shown below.

```
    proc sql;
    create table want as 
    select * from have
     where 
    case  when input(datecolumn, ddmmyy10.) ne .
    then input(datecolumn, ddmmyy10.) between '20Oct2018'd and '30Oct2018'd 
    end;
```

Comment: INPUT function reported "ERROR : invalid date value" while processing the where clause

Comment: how are your date values and you may some values which may not match the date. this is data issue I was talking about.

Comment: i have edited my answer, now you will have error but see a note in log as   NOTE: Invalid date value
 NOTE: Invalid argument to function INPUT. Missing values may be generated.